# Which module should I use to make a Kivy application using bluetooth?

Tags: python, bluetooth, kivy

I want to create a game using Bluetooth in python kivy, but I don't know if it's possible. Which modules should I use to create a kivy application in which I can use Bluetooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to make a game with Bluetooth on Android which is a Java class, you should use the `Pyjnius` module, which lets python applications use java classes.

Documentation for [Pyjnius](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

You could use Pyjnius like this:

```py
from jnius import autoclass

BluetoothAdapter = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter')
BluetoothDevice = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice')
BluetoothSocket = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket')
UUID = autoclass('java.util.UUID')

def get_socket_stream(name):
    paired_devices = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices().toArray()
    socket = None
    for device in paired_devices:
        if device.getName() == name:
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))
            recv_stream = socket.getInputStream()
            send_stream = socket.getOutputStream()
            break
    socket.connect()
    return recv_stream, send_stream

class Bluetooth():
    def __init__(nameOfDevice):
        self.recv_stream, self.send_stream = get_socket_stream(nameOfDevice)

    def send(self, cmd):
        self.send_stream.write('{}\n'.format(cmd))
        self.send_stream.flush()
```